# Не работает sumbit! через html !!! а если быть точнее то она отображается некорректно , подскажите в чем ошибка ( новичок)

Tags: html

```
    <form action="http://www.primer.ru/bookings/"method="post">
    <label for="depart">Дата вылета</label>
    <input type="date" name="depart">
    <input type="sumbit" value="Отправить">
</form>[![о][1]][1]
```

[image: Отображается как поле обычные]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="http://www.primer.ru/bookings/"method="post">
    <label for="depart">Дата вылета</label>
    <input type="date" name="depart">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Ошибка в слове `sumbit`, измените на `submit`